# Proof completion problem: I can only use primitive rules of inference, and I have contradictory premises.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Standard proof completion:

1. ~(p&q) A
2. ~(~p&q) A
3. ~(p&~q) A
4. ~(~p&~q) A
5. SHOW r

Contradicting r and then showing a contradiction seems like the obvious plan of attack, but after that I'm lost. I can only use primitive rules of inference--for instance, going from ~(A&B) to ~Av~B, or from knowing AvB and ~B to A are off limits.

My attempts so far have run into the following problem: Obviously the premises form a contradiction, but I can't crack open the negation of each premise without listing one (a premise) on a SHOW line and then negating it, but that isn't helpful, since I already know what I'm proving.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it depends on "the primitive rules of inference" you are licensed to use.

I'll give you an hint with *Natural Deduction*.

You have to use two "ausiliary" assumptions : $p$ and $q$.

We need two sub-proofs:

*i)* By $\land$-introduction, form $p$ and $q$, derive : $p \land q$.

This contradicts 1) and thus you can derive $\lnot p$, discharging the 1st ausialiary assumption $p$.

Now with $\lnot p$ and $q$ derive $\lnot p \land q$, contradicting 2); thus, derive $\lnot q$, discharging the 2nd ausiliary assumption $q$.

Up to now, we have derived $\lnot q$ with no undischarged assumptions.

*ii)* In the same way, using again $p$ and $q$ and premises 1) and 3), we derive $\lnot p$, with no undischarged assumptions.

Finally, we join the two "threads" deriving $\lnot p \land \lnot q$ by $\land$-introduction.

This contradicts 4) and thus, by $\lnot$-elimination (i.e. : $\varphi, \lnot \varphi \vdash \bot$) followed by $\bot$-elimination (i.e. : $\bot \vdash \psi$) or by [Ex falso quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), you can conclude with : $r$.

Comment: This can't be right, since you didn't use the third premise, without which there is no contradiction. I think you missed that if you conclude $\neg p \wedge \neg q$, the second auxiliary assumption $q$ reappears (because $\neg p$ depends on that).

Comment: @DeeDuu I think he does: In part (i) he uses 1 and 2 to arrive at $\neg q$, and then in part (ii) he uses 1 and 3 to arrive at $\neg p$; and of course he uses 4  in the "finally" part.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - DeeDuu's comment was writed with respect to a previous faulty edition of the proof :-)